# why "this" has a different behavior than the named selector

Tags: jquery

I'm not an expert in jquery, I've been using for a couple of week. So, sorry if my question seems obvious for you.

I have created a jquery script which works fine.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#comment<?php echo $data['id']; ?>").click(function(e) {

            $("#comment<?php echo $data['id']; ?>").prop('disabled', true);

            if ($("#comment<?php echo $data['id']; ?>").val() == 'Comment') {

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('comment/create', array('post_id' => $data['id'])); ?>",
                    success: function(data) {
                        $("#comment<?php echo $data['id']; ?>").after(data);
                        $(".form").slideDown(2000);
                    }                          
                });
            } else {

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('comment/delete', array('post_id' => $data['id'], 'user_id'=> Yii::app()->user->id)); ?>",
                    success: function(data) {
                        $("#comment<?php echo $data['id']; ?>").prop('disabled', false);
                    }
                });
            }
</script>
```

I would like to replace
all   `$("#comment<?php echo $data['id']; ?>")` by `$(this).`

When I do it, it doesn’t work as expected. For example  in the if statement,

`$("#comment<?php echo $data['id']; ?>").val() == 'Comment'`

it goes to the else part and run  the delete action instead of create

* New information

my button in html page contains the following

```
<p><input type ="button" id="comment<?php echo $data['id']; ?>" 
     value="<?php echo isset($comment_exist) ? 'Comment' : 'Cancel my Comment'; ?>"></p>
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: did you try to log the value like `console.log($(this).val(), this)`

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist no... the OP is using `this` inside a click handler so `this` should be referring to the clicked `$("#comment<?php echo $data['id']; ?>")` element

Comment: also can you share the relevant html

Comment: Whoops, totally misread the code. I'll see myself out.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist   I want to get rid of php inside my script because I want to put externalize my js script

Comment: @ArunPJohny  I updated the post with  the content of the button in the html file

Comment: You can try storing the 'id' value in a HTML5 `-data` attribute, and access it using jQuery &mdash; this will prevent the need to embed PHP within your JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand `$(this)`, first understand `this`

inside a function `this` is a reference to the object context for that function. Outside of any function, it refers to the global scope, and in a web browser, that is the `window` object.

`$(this)`, then, is just a jquery wrapper for `this`.

You're using `this` both inside and outside of function contexts.

**1)** Your first case has no function context -- you're in the global scope and `this` won't give you what you need -- so you'll need to do something like this:

```
 $('[id^="comment"]').click(function(e) {...
```

This will then set up a click-handler for any element whose id starts with "comment", like, "comment_23" or "commentA" ...

**2)** The second usage, just inside the click handler, should probably work with a simple replacement -- you just need a reference to the object that was clicked. Inside a click-handler, that's `this`.

```
if ($(this).val() == 'Comment') { ...
```

**3)** Now, the usages inside of the success callbacks for `ajax` are a different issue. In there, a new object context is set up -- `this` refers to the ajax object. So declare a reference to the outer `this` before you get into the ajax function:

```
var $thisClicked = $(this);
```

Then use this reference in your success callbacks, e.g.:

```
   var $thisClicked = $(this);

   $.ajax( ....

                success: function(data) {
                    $thisClicked.after(data);
                    $(".form").slideDown(2000);
                }
```

Comment: That's as clean and simple of an explanation of JavaScript's `this` as you're likely to get anywhere.

Comment: sorry... isn't the OP using `this` inside a click handler where `this` should refer to the clicked element which is the same as `#comment<?php echo $data['id']; ?>`

Comment: Arun: the OP is using this both inside the click-handler, and outside of it, and also in the success callbacks, I'll update my answer accordingly....

Comment: @Faust  thank you for the code inside ajax,  but what about the other ones.

Comment: @Faust  $('[id^="comment"]').click(function(e) {...  will take all the comments, my problem is that I want to select only the one selected

Comment: @klark: I've update my answer, added guidance for the cases, and cleaned up the order

Comment: Thank you very much @Faust, it works excactly as you described

Answer (score 0):

as other user mentioned, *this* may not work as you expect

it took me some time to understand how scopes and closures works on javascript. take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/L5qna/ , it may throw some light on your path.

in your case I would do something like

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var myElement = $("#comment<?php echo $data['id']; ?>");
        $(myElement).click(function(e) {
```

you should be able to use *myElement* everywhere inside your *ready* function; and functions defined inside it